# Getting access to parameter in lcoud function when cloud function is called from android app

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-functions

```
FirebaseFunctions.getInstance().getHttpsCallable("onCommentMentionCreated")
                            .call(data);
```

The code above is what I use to call a firebase cloud function from an android app. The `data` variable used as a parameter in the `call` function is a Hashmap. I'd like to know how to get access to it on the server side.

Comment: Is there something unclear in the documentation?  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable

Comment: @DougStevenson upon reading the docs again, I think this may have been a consequence of coding too late at night.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a corresponding `Callable` Cloud Function with something like this:

```
exports. onCommentMentionCreated = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  // ...
});
```

The data you're passing from the Android app is available in the `data` argument.

For a more complete example than the snippets in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable), have a look at the [full corresponding Cloud Functions code](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable).